# Shorter awk to print starting from Nth field

Tags: bash, awk

To print fields starting from N, say N=5

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){if(i<NF){printf "%s%s",$i,OFS}else{print $i}}}' 
# This is a bit lengthy!
```

Any shorter `awk` available?

Comment: I don't think there is no. You could use a while loop which would be marginally shorter, but it would only work on a single line. Also i think your previous question was fine as the examples were quite short and also related.

Comment: shouldn't it be `i<=NF` ? and on my machine, it prints the field in separate lines.. did you want to print fields of a line in same line?

Comment: Why not `awk -v n=5 '{for (i=n; i<NF;i++) line=(i==n) ? $i : line OFS $i; print line}' file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you.  Marginally  shorter..

Answer (score 1):

With the default field separator and GNU awk (version 4+), this is marginally shorter:

```
gawk '{ sub(/^\s*(\S+\s+){4}/, "") }1' file
```

This removes 4 fields from the start of the line, including any leading whitespace.

Comment: Requires gawk 4.0+.

Answer (score 1):

For very simple applications, `cut` may be better suited:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" | cut -d' ' -f5-
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Please re-check the question, OP wants a solution only in `awk`

Comment: @Inian, that may be the case, but from the context of the OP it seems a case of using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. It may, or may not help them, but it doesn't stop this being a reasonable solution (after all, one of the requirements was that it be "shorter").